# Import statement fails in Angular module.ts file

Tags: angular, typescript

I will start by naming three key files in my angular project with their paths:

> ClientApp/app/app.module.ts
>
> ClientApp/app/app.component.ts
>
> ClientApp/shop/productList.component.ts

In my app.module.ts file, the second of two import statements fails:

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ProductList } from './shop/productList.component';
```

> Build:Cannot find module './shop/productList.component'.

As seen from the list of paths I gave, there IS actually an export class ProductList found in Clientapp/shop/productList.component.ts, so why cannot the file be found?

Is there any settings file that restricts the search of ts files to specific folders? I do have the following include:

```
"include": [
    "./ClientApp",
    "./wwwroot/ts"
  ],
```

... in the tsconfig.json, in case this is relevant. Any ideas please?

Comment: Try: `import { ProductList } from '../shop/productList.component';`, or move the `shop` folder under `ClientApp/app`.

Comment: Worked, thank you! Wow.